# Cross-server ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, jsonp, cross-server

I've run into a situation where one of my company's clients is building a website with our service, but would like to include on our site the podcasts that get posted into a table dynamically generated on a page of their main business site.

I've done a bit with ajax before, I know one of the biggest hurdles is using ajax to access content on a site hosted on a different server. From my research I gather that JSONP is the best solution in a situation like this, but for argument's sake let's say I know nothing of how their server is configured (and have no realistic way to find out) and that I don't know much about JSON (which is true).

I probably shouldn't hope for a silver bullet in a situation like this, but can someone point me at least in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) in situations like this.

Comment: The CMS my company uses outputs pages as static HTML, so I'm not able to use any php..

Comment: Do you have access to the CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own service with PHP that calls the AJAX service, that way you can call any remote service you want but the ajax call is to your domain. I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: I'd use the terminology of a "proxy" to help explain what you've describe, but yes this is also a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, have a look at [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain), otherwise, throw one of the following header functions into script that serves the request and see if this helps.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://permitted_domain.com');
```

This is something that the client browser supports, so your mileage may vary

for a non AJAX/Javascript solution, URL fetching mechanisms like [file_get_conents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (note [this configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)) or using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) can be used to achieve similar (if not more inline) results